# Consoles read value of variable but return gives undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, return

I am having a scope issue.

```
function boo() {
    var ajax5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax5.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax5.readyState == 4) {
            xxx5 = (ajax5.responseText);

            var obj = JSON.parse(xxx5);
            d2 = obj.myvariable;

            return d2;

        }
    };
    ajax5.open("GET", "URL TO SCRIPT (CORS HEADERS ENABLED)", true);
    ajax5.send(null);


};


var xxx = boo();
```

If replace return d2 with console.log(d2) I get the value in console.

With return d2; I get undefined.

I want xxx to hold the value of d2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "return d2" is of "onreadystatechange" not of "boo" function. That why your xxx is undefined